# Cannot start npm in the react native

Tags: react-native, npm

I'm trying to work with React Native  I try to run the application with 
**npm** start

And receive this error:

```
> ERROR  Metro Bundler can't listen on port 8081 Loading dependency
> graph...npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 11 npm ERR!
> MyFirstDemo@0.0.1 start: `node
> node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start` npm ERR! Exit status
> 11 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the MyFirstDemo@0.0.1 start script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
> additional logging output above. npm ERR! A complete log of this run
> can be found in: npm ERR!    
> /home/nidhi/.npm/_logs/2018-09-04T12_11_05_454Z-debug.log
```

can any one help me?

Comment: what operating system are you using? Linux?

Comment: Please edit your post with the error, eventually, tell us if you use vanilla react native or expo

Comment: @SGhaleb, Linux

Comment: run this command to find out what is using which ports "netstat -a -b -o"

Comment: You can try in terminal ... `lsof -i :8081` to see what is using the port, then follow this to correctly/safely kill the process.... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/when-should-i-not-kill-9-a-process/8918#8918

Comment: @SGhaleb it is working now. Thank u all for ur response.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you already have a packager running, or just something else running on port 8081, thus the packager tries to start but can't, as something's already listening on that port.

If you're on your development machine, and have no other meaningful node.js process running, then you *could* execute the following to sort it out.

```
killall node && npm start
```

**If you do not want to kill every node process on your machine**, hey, some may be important... You'll want to only kill the process running on that port.

Note: should work on MacOS and Linux.

1. See if there is a process on that port (optional step)

   ```
   lsof -i:8081
   ```
2. kill it (violently), assuming there was something running on port 8081

   ```
   kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8081)
   ```
3. Now try run the packager again.

   ```
   npm start
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when you are running another process with the same port (8081)
First see the process ids, which are running at the same port.
try,

```
lsof -i :8081
```

The output results as below.
[process that are running using the same port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QJAp.png)

You can kill those,

```
kill -9 454 21922
```

Try npm start again.
If those commands are not working, try to run them with sudo.

```
sudo lsof -i :8081
sudo kill -9 454 21922
```